# Physical Interpretation of an Elementary Inequality in Kinematics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I recently came across the following question: suppose a point mass moves a distance $d_1$ for $t_1$ seconds at a velocity $v_1$, then accelerates instantaneously to a velocity $v_2$ and travels a distance $d_2$ for $t_2$ seconds at this velocity. Show that $$\frac{v_1d_1 +v_2d_2}{d_1+d_2} \geq \frac{v_1t_1+v_2t_2}{t_1 + t_2}$$
A mathematical proof is quite straightforward. What I'm wondering is is there a way to see this directly?

Comment: How is a straightforward mathematical proof not "direct"? Do you mean "intuitively", or maybe "physically"? "easily"?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a more heuristic idea why this should be true.

Comment: Mathematically, it's the [CS inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality): $(\sum_i d_i)^2\leq \sum_j v_jd_j \sum_k d_k/v_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can view it pictorally. For when the second velocity is very high, the LHS tends to the second velocity. However the RHS tends to the average of the two velocities.